# sql server 2005 vss writer service is not installed. How do I fix

Tags: sql-server

I attempted to update sql server 2005 with SP2.  I get a failure due to not starting vss writer.  When I go into services, I see that vss writer is not installed.  (not even listed in services).  When I check my other redundant servers, I see that vss writer service is installed.  How do I add the service?

Answer (score 1):

find the SqlWriter.msi off the SQL Server DVD and run it.